# how to write html div content using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am trying to create a floating video player on a D3 tree
(http://bl.ocks.org/csarsurvey/8999077).

Brightcove has a working example including Html, CSS and Javascript. See

https://docs.brightcove.com/en/player/brightcove-player/samples/floating-video.html

The following code should be created dynamically via javascript:

```
<div id="playerWrapper" class="drag">
<iframe src='//players.brightcove.net/1752604059001/15933ac1-884c-40e0-8cae-a06c7d9e4c0a_default/index.html?videoId=4511340777001' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I wrote the following function, but this destroys the tree and creates a new page instead of floating on the tree as intended.

```
    function node_onMouseOver(d) {
    if (!d._children) {
        document.body.innerHTML="<div id=" +
        "\"playerWrapper\"" +
        " class="   + 
        "\"drag\"" +
        " style=" +
        "position:fixed;top:246px;left:984px;" + ">" +
     "<iframe src="  +
     "video.html " +
     "allowfullscreen=" +
     "\"\"" +
     " webkitallowfullscreen="  +
     "\"\"" +
    " mozallowfullscreen=" +
     "\"\"" +
     " frameborder=" +
     "\"0\"" +
     " width=" +
     "\"650\"" +
     " height=" +
     "\"500\""  +
    " ></iframe> </div>"
            }
    }
```

How can I create a floating draggable video on top of the tree located initially at the specified node depending on a user event?

warm regards,
KrikKrak

Comment: Use appendChild, not innerHtml

Comment: The code you've added did not create a floating div for me. But, I have recreated the code using javascript. If you want, I will post it as an answer.

Comment: Umashankar Das, yes, please post the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
function node_onMouseOver(d) {
    if (!d._children) {
        var el = '<div id="playerWrapper"  class="drag"  style="position:fixed;top:246px;left:984px;" <iframe src="video.html" allowfullscreen=""' +
            ' webkitallowfullscreen=""  frameborder="0"  width="650"  height="500"></iframe> </div> ';

        $('#ID').append(el);
    }
}
```

I hope it's work.